# Java adding escape characters in String value returned from MySql

Tags: json, string, spring-boot

I have Stored JSON as a String in a column in My SQL.

{  "cities": [ "Delhi", "Gurgaon", "Ghaziabad"],"comments" : "This isResponse Template" }

But When I get the Response through WebService, Java Adds '\' along with qoutes :

\"cities\": [ \"Delhi\", \"Gurgaon\", \"Ghaziabad\"], \"comments\" : \"This is Response Template\" }"

Comment: what is your issue then ?

Comment: it should be same as { "cities": [ "Delhi", "Gurgaon", "Ghaziabad"],"comments" : "This isResponse Template" } and should not have '\' added in it in order to maintain the JSON Structure.

Comment: What is the data type of column in SQL ?

Comment: its LongText in MySQL and String in Java